# Firebase.update failed : first argument contains undefined in property

Tags: javascript, firebase

I have a simple Firebase function that updates some data. However, the interpreter says that the first argument contains "undefined" in property 'users.tester1'. Can somebody help me please?

```
var objify = function() {
  var rv = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; ++i)
      rv[arguments[i]] = rv[arguments[i+1]];
    return rv;
}

    addUser("tester1", []);

var addUser = function(name, edges){
  if(!checkIfUsernameExists(name) && !checkIfNodeNameExists(name) && !checkIfEdgeNameExists(name)){
    var time = Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP;

    //HERE: I think the error is on this line 
    refs.users.update(objify(name, "filler"));

    refs.users.child(name).set({
      "id" : time,
      "edges" : "filler"
    });
    refs.users.child(name).child("edges").update({
      "to" : "filler",
      "from" : "filler"
    });

    addNode(new Node(name, time, name));

    for(var e in edges){
      refs.users.child(name).child("edges/to").update(objify(edges[e].name, true));
      addEdge(new Edge(edges[e].name, time, edges[e].to, edges[e].arrows));
      //TODO add a "from" edge so that you know who wants to eat you
    }
    refs.users.child(name).child("edges/to").set({"filler" : null});
  } else {
    alert("user/node/edge name taken.");
  }
};
```

Answer (score 59, accepted):

When you pass an object to Firebase, the values of the properties can be a value or null (in which case the property will be removed). They can not be `undefined`, which is what you're passing in according to the error.

Simply running this snippet in isolation shows the problem:

```
var objify = function() {
  var rv = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; ++i)
      rv[arguments[i]] = rv[arguments[i+1]];
    return rv;
}
objify("name", "filler")
```

Results in:

> {name: undefined, filler: undefined}

My best bet is that you want to pass key/value pairs into `objify` as even/odd parameters. In that case you want to change the function to:

```
var objify = function() {
  var rv = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i+=2)
      rv[arguments[i]] = arguments[i+1];
    return rv;
}
objify("name", "filler")
```

Results in:

> {name: "filler"}

Comment: I had declared variables `pub.email`, `pub.displayName`, etc.  I got this error.  I added `pub.email = null;` for these declarations, for example, and now the error is gone.  `.onAuthStateChanged` fills them or not depending on user being signed in and this works.

Comment: I just had an issue with this and I use something like: `value: valueOrNull(value),` where `valueOrNull` is `value => value (value === undefined ? null : value)`.  Can I respectfully suggest that it's a violation of the principle of least surprise for Firebase to treat null and undefined differently since JS does not?  Both mean "not known" so why can't Firebase translate undefined to null internally?  The current erroring behavior on undefined makes it harder to use object spread and assign etc because it forces us to null out potentially undefined values ...

Answer (score 30):

to make sure your object does not contain any undefined props use this simple trick:

```
JSON.parse( JSON.stringify(YourJsonData ) )
```

For more info take a look at this codePen: http://codepen.io/ajmueller/pen/gLaBLX

Comment: The unbelievable simple solution. This should be the accepted answer! Thanks for saving my day!

Comment: I am getting this error: `SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0`

Comment: @ShajeelAfzal - if JSON.stringify or JSON.parse doesn't work on your data that mean it's not a correct JSON object...

Answer (score 2):

The underlying Firebase library throws an error when you try to update a property with the value of undefined. It will allow null (and will essentially ignore them).

You'll need your raw transformer to ensure that it ignores all prototype methods and properties and converts undefined to null or removes any properties with with undefined values altogether.

```
var addUser = function(name, edges){
  if(!checkIfUsernameExists(name) && !checkIfNodeNameExists(name) && !checkIfEdgeNameExists(name)){
    var time = Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP;

    //HERE: I think the error is on this line 
    refs.users.update(objify(name, "filler"));

    refs.users.child(name).set({
      "id" : time || null,
      "edges" : "filler" || null
    });
    refs.users.child(name).child("edges").update({
      "to" : "filler" || null,
      "from" : "filler" || null
    });

    addNode(new Node(name, time, name));
```

Answer (score 0):

Like said above, you need all `undefined` values to be `null` if you want them to save as empty values in firebase.

I take this approach to correct all nested values.

```
  //to search and replace    
    const replaceAll  =(s="",f="",r="")=>  s.replace(new RegExp(f.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&'), 'g'), r)

    //to save 
   firebase.database().ref(`path`).update(JSON.parse(replaceAll(JSON.stringify(val),"undefined","null")))
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the `Object.keys()` method:

```
var key1 = Object.keys(firstPaymentsData)[0],
    key2 = Object.keys(firstPaymentsData[key1])[0],
    uid  = firstPaymentsData[key1][key2].uid;
```