# Vuefire Firebase update issues

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, vue.js, vuejs2, vuefire

I'm having som issues with updating Firebase from VueFire. I m trying to use the following method, but it yells at me if I leave any field blank (which is supposed to happen often in setup) Any idea why this gets mad if .update with a blank field?

> Error: Uncaught Error: Firebase.update failed: First argument contains undefined in property 'businesses.somebusiness.video'

```
updatePost(post) {
        postsRef.child(post['.key']).update({
          name: post.name,
          video: post.video,
          story: post.story,
          cover: post.cover,
          card: post.card
        })
      },
```

At one point I had the above re-written like so:

```
updatePost: function (post) {
        const businesschildKey = post['.key'];
        delete post['.key'];
        /* Set the updated post value */
        this.$firebaseRefs.posts.child(businesschildKey).set(post)
      },
```

It worked amazingly but deleting the key seemed to cause weird ordering issues in Vue. I would prefer to stick with the top method if I can find a way to not have it trow an error if one is left blank.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34708715/392102

Comment: Interesting, but struggling to understand how to fix that when my properties could be either `' '` or have a value depending on the business.

Comment: Is `post.video` actually undefined? Try `video: post.video || null`

Comment: Adding the `|| null` to the end seems to have fixed it. Thanks! What did that do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34708715/392102),

> When you pass an object to Firebase, the values of the properties can
>   be a value or `null` (in which case the property will be removed). They
>   can not be `undefined`, which is what you're passing in according to the
>   error.

Your error message suggests that `post.video`'s value is `undefined`. You can use logical-or to provide a fallback value like so:

```
  video: post.video || null,
```

That means whenever `post.video` has a false-y value, the expression will evaluate to `null`. That could catch empty string or numeric 0, though. To be more precisely correct, you should use

```
  video: typeof post.video === 'undefined' ? null : post.video,
```

If you need to do this check for many values, you can write a function for it:

```
function nullIfUndefined(value) {
  return typeof value === 'undefined' ? null : value;
}
```

then your expression would just be

```
  video: nullIfUndefined(post.video),
```